# Find all possible values $\sqrt{i}+\sqrt{-i}$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Find all possible values of $\sqrt{i} + \sqrt{-i}$. Here $i= \sqrt{-1}$.

My solution which didn't work.

\begin{eqnarray}a+ib &=& \sqrt{i}+\sqrt{-i}\\ &=& \sqrt{i}+\sqrt{i^2i}\\ &=& \sqrt{i}+\sqrt{i}i\end{eqnarray}
\begin{eqnarray}(a+ib)^2 &=& \left(\sqrt{i}+\sqrt{i}i\right)^2\\a^2-b^2+2abi &=& -1-i-2i\\ &=& -1-3i\end{eqnarray}
\begin{cases}a^2-b^2=-1\\2ab=-3\end{cases}
\begin{cases}a^2-b^2=-1\\4a^2b^2=9\end{cases}
\begin{eqnarray}\left(a^2+b^2\right)^2 &=& \left(a^2-b^2\right)^2+4a^2b^2\\ &=& 1+9\\ &=& 10\end{eqnarray}
\begin{cases}a^2-b^2=-1\\a^2+b^2=\sqrt{10}\end{cases}
\begin{eqnarray}2a^2 &=& \sqrt{10}-1\\a^2=\frac{\sqrt{10}-1}2\\ a &=& \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{10}-1}2}\\b &=& \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{10}+1}2}\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Please do not use pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually liked your approach! Unfortunately, a misconception and a miscalculation took you off the rails.

The misconception comes from the fact that we're used to thinking of $\sqrt{\alpha}$ as a single number, which is sensible as long as we're only dealing with non-negative real numbers. However, beyond that, we need to consider it to indicate one of *up to two different* numbers, which we can't narrow down further without more information. Your book doesn't help this by saying things like "$i=\sqrt{-1},$" unfortunately.

In particular, we must keep this in mind for any complex number $z$: $$\sqrt{z^2}=\pm z.\tag{$\star$}$$

> \begin{eqnarray}a+ib &=& \sqrt{i}+\sqrt{-i}\\ &=& \sqrt{i}+\sqrt{i^2i}\\ &=& \sqrt{i}+\sqrt{i}i\end{eqnarray}

We've got to be a little careful trying to use the property $$\sqrt{\alpha\beta}=\sqrt{\alpha}\sqrt{\beta}$$ when $\alpha$ and $\beta$ aren't nonnegative reals, because of $(\star).$ We should instead have $$a+ib=\sqrt{i}\pm\sqrt{i}i.$$

> \begin{eqnarray}(a+ib)^2 &=& \left(\sqrt{i}+\sqrt{i}i\right)^2\\a^2-b^2+abi &=& -1-i-2i\\ &=& -1-3i\end{eqnarray}

I'm not sure what happened on the right-hand side. It should end up being $-2,$ which of course changes everything! From there, you'll see that $a=0$ and $b=\pm\sqrt2,$ giving us $\pm\sqrt{2}i$ as two of our possible solutions. Considering also the case $a+ib=\sqrt{i}-\sqrt{i}i,$ we obtain instead $b=0$ and $a=\pm\sqrt 2,$ which gives us the other two solutions: $\pm\sqrt{2}$!

However, even if this *had* been correct, some more things went wrong on the way, as well.

> \begin{cases}a^2-b^2=-1\\2ab=-3\end{cases}
>   \begin{cases}a^2-b^2=-1\\4a^2b^2=9\end{cases}
>   \begin{eqnarray}\left(a^2+b^2\right)^2 &=& \left(a^2-b^2\right)^2+4a^2b^2\\ &=& 1+9\\ &=& 10\end{eqnarray}
>   \begin{cases}a^2-b^2=-1\\a^2+b^2=\sqrt{10}\end{cases}

Fine so far, but only because we can't have $a^2+b^2=-\sqrt{10}$ when $a,b$ are real!

> \begin{eqnarray}2a^2 &=& \sqrt{10}-1\\a^2 &=&\frac{\sqrt{10}-1}2\\ a &=& \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{10}-1}2}\end{eqnarray}

Here, again, we should have used $(\star)$ to instead have obtained $$a=\pm\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{10}-1}2},$$ and similarly, we'd have had $$b=\pm\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{10}+1}2}.$$

Comment: Great , thank you very much, because of you guys , I really like math a lot.

Comment: You're very welcome! I just realized there was something grievously wrong with my answer. It should be fixed, now.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $i=\frac{1}{2}(1+i)^2$ and $-i=\frac{1}{2}(1-i)^2$.

Comment: How you got idea , to use this expression?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Express $$i=e^{i{\pi\over2}}\\-i=e^{i{3\pi\over2}}$$then $$x_1=r_1e^{i\theta_1} , x_1^2=i\\x_2=r_2e^{i\theta_2} , x^2_2=-i$$what are the possible values of $x_1+x_2$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If $(a+bi)^2=\alpha+\beta i$, then:
$$a=\pm\sqrt{\frac{\alpha\pm\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}}{2}}, b=\pm\sqrt{\frac{-\alpha\pm\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}}{2}}$$

Can you use this to find $\sqrt i$ and $\sqrt{-i}$ in the form $a+bi$?

If you're wondering how I got these expressions, it's a nice bit of algebra from the first statement. Try it yourself!

Comment: Got it , thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Cameron Buie has written an excellent answer, but adding my two cents to it, I would like to elaborate this:

> \begin{eqnarray}(a+ib)^2 &=& \left(\sqrt{i}+\sqrt{i}i\right)^2\\a^2-b^2+abi &=& -1-i-2i\\ &=& -1-3i\end{eqnarray}

The part where it wrong was in squaring the $\sqrt{i}$ it must be i and not -1 also, $\sqrt{i}.i$ squared would be -i. And evaluating the third term, it would be a nice -2 that satisfies the answer that Cameron Buie points out in their answer.

P.S. This was supposed to be a comment/suggestion but since I don't have the required reputation, I wrote it as a separate answer.